# How to unhide GRUB menu

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub

I upgraded to Ubuntu 20.04 and after the laptop battery died while in Windows, Ubuntu could not load at all. I ran boot-repair and now it goes in Ubuntu without showing the GRUB menu. I read the help for the simple config and tried several options that should fix the problem, but no luck. Uncommenting the `style=menu` does nothing.

My GRUB is:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
##GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=/dev/disk/by-uuid/30a0ce15-7a08-48a2-ac6b-ba73822c05c2"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

the output from boot-repair is at
[bootinfo](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/xGndTBtDcP/)

Comment: To "always" stop at the menu; Hit `ESC` *once* just after the BIOS displays clears.

Comment: did you run `update-grup` after changing config file ?

Comment: I did run update-grub. also touching any key makes the system go into a dead end and it never starts anything, just a plain black screen forever.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried editing my `/etc/default/grub` and funny thing is that despite the setting for `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE` my menu displays. I have tried hidden, countdown, and commented out. Possibly this is because I have a multi OS system.I don't have access to a single boot linux system right now to test on.

I don't intend to sound smug by mentioning the obvious (don't worry I failed to do it myself), but have you run `update-grub` or `grub-mkconfig` after setting `GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu`?

Comment: same here: the setting is HIDDEN on another laptop and the menu always shows.